# how do I parse year column to number in R

Tags: r, parsing

Using this data File POP/1-1: Total population (both sexes combined) by region, subregion and country, annually for 1950-2100 (thousands) High Fertility Variant, I have to "parse the year column to a number."

the years range from 2020 to 2100.

I dont know what it means to parse the year to a number pls help

Comment: Hello Cristina, welcome to SO. Please, read this help page to know how to provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Cristina - as mentioned, it would help to see the format of the data provided to you. It looks like it may be adapted from: https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Standard/Population/ But it sounds like you have years potential combined with a single column. Consider something like `dput(head(UNdata1))` and edit your question with the results (assuming `UNdata1` is a data frame you have).

Answer (score 1):

```
as.numeric(Year)
```

replace Year for the name of the column

Comment: UNdata1$2020:2100<-parse_number(UNdata1$2020:2100)   I tried to parse the year columns to numbers like this, but I get an error stating Error: unexpected numeric constant in "UNdata1$2020"